# How can I reverse the contents of an ImageIcon array thats been created in a different class?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java-stream, reverse

I currently have an ArrayList called ImageShow. Ive been trying to find ways to swap the contents of this array around in Java, but I haven't found a way.

```
ImageShow.add(new ImageIcon(file.listFiles()[a].getAbsolutePath())); //Adding the files into an imageicon array
```

Thats how I put the contents of a file into the array, then I want it to be able to reverse the contents of all the items inside the array. For example, the array would contain 15.png, 23.png, 32.png, 47.png, 58.png, 64.png, 76.png, 81.png in that order, but I want to be able to press a button and it reverses that. Can anyone help? Ive found ways to do it with a string, but not a ImageIcon array.

Thanks.

Comment: So you swap the first value with the last value. Then you swap the 2nd value with the 2nd last value. etc. So you write a loop to do this. When you get half way through the array you are finished as all items have been swapped. The contents (String or ImageIcon) of the array is irrelevant  Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: So in your last question you ask about "sorting" and in this question you ask about "reversing". "Reversing" doesn't care about the order of the items in the List. It just reversed the items in the list. "Sorting" implies you have so rules to follow and you would use a Comparator. Ask a clear question and don't mix terminology.

Comment: Also, when you get help don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved. You have had help with both question your have asked.

Comment: Hey there camickr. I couldn't figure out how to sort the in the first question I made, although one of the answers did help. Ive decided that I would put the Array in order the first time, and only have it sort by one way (price), which is just reversing the order. I didnt know how to mark them as answered aswell, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) would be an easy way to deal with this.  When passing a single arg to  [ImageIcon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) that arg is both the filename and description.

```
final Comparator<ImageIcon> sortBy = Comparator.comparing(ImageIcon::getDescription).reversed();
List<ImageIcon> sortedList = ImageShow.stream().sorted(sortBy).collect(toList());
```

Comment: Really? Why is using a Stream "an easy way to deal with this" when you can also sort the list in-place using `ImageShow.sort(sortBy);`? Besides that, when the task is to reverse the existing list order, a plain `Collections.reverse(ImageShow);` would do as well.

Comment: good points :) i guess i should have put more thought into it..